# Django - Paginate with another GET request; not working with just pagination page number

Tags: django

I'm building a page with pagination and a filter form (2 GET requests).  If the URL includes both pagination and filter results, something like `/questions/?page=2&all_questions=on`, it works fine.  It also works if it just has filter results, something like `/questions/?all_questions=on`.

However if it only has the pagination page result, something like `/questions/?page=1`, no results are shown.

So I figured I need to do something with the views so that if there is only a page number in the URL, a default filter will be given.  I know I probably need to add something to the Try and Except section of pagination, but I'm stumped as to the actual code I need to write.

```
def questions_index(request):

    user = request.user
    form = QuestionFilterForm(request.GET or None)
    question_list = []
    if not form.is_bound:
        question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['all_questions'] | (form.cleaned_data['general_questions'] & form.cleaned_data['location_all_gta']) == True:
            question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
        elif form.cleaned_data['location_all_gta'] == True:
            question_list += Question.objects.filter(question_type=1).order_by('-date_created')
        else:
            if form.cleaned_data['general_questions'] == True:
                question_list += Question.objects.filter(question_type=2).order_by('-date_created')
            if form.cleaned_data['location_toronto'] == True:
                question_list += Question.objects.filter(location='1').order_by('-date_created')

    paginator = Paginator(question_list, 15)

    # Pagination
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        questions = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        questions = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        questions = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    ### I need to write something here...
    except (url has no filter result)  
        give default filter 

    return render(request, 'questions_index.html', {'questions': questions, 'user': user, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Have you tried:
question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
paginator = Paginator(question_list, 15)
questions = paginator.page(page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is at the beginning, not at the end. When you write:

```
if not form.is_bound:
    question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
```

This condition will only be met if `request.GET` is empty. The `is_bound` method will return `True` if you give any data to it, no matter if the keys of the dictionary are not form fields ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound)). In the case you described, `request.GET` will contain the `page` key only.

A possible solution is to rewrite this part as:

```
if not form.is_bound or (len(request.GET) == 1 and 'page' in request.GET):
    question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  I will give bounty when the time limit expires